# How to get the src of an image tag using QRegExp and QString

Tags: regex, qt, qstring, qregexp

So I have got a string in my app which contains an html img tag

```
<img src="imagsource.jpg" width="imageWidth" />
```

Now I want to extract the image tag and its `src` attribute in two different strings. So what I tried to do is this:

```
QRegExp imageRegex("\\<img[^\\>]*src\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"[^\\>]*\\>", Qt::CaseInsensitive);

int a = imageRegex.indexIn(description);
int b = a + imageRegex.matchedLength();

QString imgTag = description.mid(a,b); // this kind of works but doesn't return the img tag properly (extra information is included)

// how to obtain the "src" attribute, I have tried this: src\s*=\s*\"(.+?)" but it doesn't work
QString imgSrc = ??
```

I have tried to look at other posts regarding how to extract strings from other string using regex, I have tried to use the same patterns in `QRegExp` but they don't seem to give the correct result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/3558278

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try

`<img(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\ssrc\s*=\s*(?:(['"])([\S\s]*?)\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>`

https://regex101.com/r/qaQPPU/1

Where, the *src* value is in capture group 2.

Readable regex

```
 < img                  # Begin img tag
 (?= \s )
 (?=                    # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s src \s* = \s*       # src Attribute
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (1), Quote
           ( [\S\s]*? )           # (2), src Value
           \1 
      )
 )
                        # Have the value, just match the rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+

 >                      # End tag
```

***Update***

Use the Qt version 5 or greater (5.11 ?).

Using that version is more *Perl* like regex.

Ref: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html

Example:

```
QRegularExpression re("<img(?=\\s)(?=(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*?\\ssrc\\s*=\\s*(?:(['\"])([\\S\\s]*?)\\1))\\s+(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match("<img src=\"imagsource.jpg\"     width=\"imageWidth\" />", 1);
if (match.hasMatch()) {
    QString matched = match.captured(2); // matched -> imagsource.jpg
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @sin I made a mistake in typing the `img` tag structure, but I have changed  it. Your regex doesn't seem to work. My code is: 
`QRegExp imageRegex("<img(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*?\ssrc\s*=\s*(?:(['\"])([\S\s]*?)\1))\s+(?:\"[\S\s]*?\"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>", Qt::CaseInsensitive);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<img.*src=(?:"(.*?)"|'(.*?)').*>
```

https://regex101.com/r/qaQPPU/3

It will capture the entire tag in the whole match, then the contents of the src tag in the first group.